# How to clone a repo with a azure devops link and an ssh key?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a dev.azure repo link and an ssh key. I have added that key to my public keys in my Azure DevOps account but when I click on the repo link, the browser says that my account has not been given access. Similar problems pop up when trying through the terminal. Thankful for any help, I am a complete Git noob

Answer (score 1):

Log in to the machine you want to run the '**`git clone`**' command with SSH, then try to check with the following things to fix the issue:

1. Open a shell window (such as **`PowerShell`**, **`Bash`**, etc..) to run the following command to generate the SSH keys (public key and private key) into the **`.ssh`** folder under the root directory of current login user.

   ```bash
   ssh-keygen
   ```
2. After successfully generating the SSH keys, go to "**User settings**" > "**SSH Public Keys**" > "**+ New key**" in your Azure DevOps organization. Copy and add the public key to the "**`Public Key Data`**" field. Avoid adding whitespace or new lines into the "**`Public Key Data`**" field, as they can cause Azure DevOps to use an invalid public key. Remove the extra whitespace or new lines from the end of the content.
3. you can run the command below to test the connection.

   ```bash
   ssh -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com
   ```

   If it is the first time connecting using SSH, you should receive the following output:

   ```bash
   The authenticity of host 'ssh.dev.azure.com (<IP>)' can't be established.
   RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxx.
   This key is not known by any other names
   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
   ```

   Compare the **`SHA256 Fingerprint`** with that displayed on the "User settings" > "SSH Public Keys" page of Azure DevOps. If same, enter '**`yes`**' to continue.

   [image]
4. After successfully completing step **`#3`**, you can see the host "**`ssh.dev.azure.com`**" has been added into the **`known_hosts`** file under the **`.ssh`** folder.

   [image]
5. After above steps, you can run '**`git clone`**' command with the SSH URL of the git repository to clone the repository on the machine.

   ```bash
   git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/{organization}/{project}/{repo}
   ```

   [image]

For more details, you can reference the documentation "[**Use SSH key authentication**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops)".

---

**EDIT_1:**

To access a Git repo in Azure DevOps, you need to check with the following things:

- Ensure you have been added as a user in the Azure DevOps organization where the Git repo is in. And you also have been assigned with the **`Basic`** access level at least. If you do not have the access to the organization, try to contact the **`PCA`** (**`Project Collection Administrators`**) of this organization to invite you into the organization and assign you with the required access.
- Ensure you have been added as a member of the project where the Git repo is in. If you do not have the access to the project, try to contact the **`PCA`** or **`PA`** (**`Project Administrators`**) of this project to add you into the project.
- Ensure you have the '**`Read`**' permission at least to the git repo you want to clone. If you do not have the permission, try to contact the **`PCA`** or **`PA`** to grant you the required permissions to the git repo.

After above things, follow the steps I shared previously to generate the SSH keys, add the SSH public key to Azure DevOps, test the connection and run the '**`git clone`**' with SSH.

**Note:**

- When adding the SSH public key to Azure DevOps, you need to login to the web page of the Azure DevOps organization where the Git repo is in, then go to "**User settings**" > "**SSH Public Keys**" > "**+ New key**" to add the SSH public key (Just as mentioned in above step **`#2`**.).
- The URL used to the '**`git clone`**' command should look like "**`git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/{organization}/{project}/{repo}`**".

  ```bash
  git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/{organization}/{project}/{repo}
  ```

  **`{organization}`** is the name of Azure DevOps organization where the Git repo is in.

  **`{project}`** is the name of project where the Git repo is in.

  **`{repo}`** is the name of Git repo.

[image]

---

Comment: In step 2, do I copy the ssh key that I have been given or the one generated by ssh-keygen. Please note that this repo isn't mine and someone is trying to give me access by staring the repo link and the ssh key.

Comment: Also for step 3, I am getting the following error:

"remote: Shell access is not supported.
shell request failed on channel 0"

Comment: @NKRVVI, For step **`#2`**, Yes, you need to open the **`.pub`** file generated in the **`.ssh`** folder, then copy its content to the "**`Public Key Data`**" field in Azure DevOps. Don't forget to remove the extra whitespace or new lines from the end of the content in the "**`Public Key Data`**" field.

Comment: @NKRVVI, For step **`#3`**, if you get this output, that means everything is configured correctly. See the screenshot I shared in step **`#3`**, you can see I also got the same output. In the documentation shared above, it also has stated this. Also noticed the warning that says the host "**`ssh.dev.azure.com`**" has been added into the **`known_hosts`** file.

Comment: Then what exactly do i do with the ssh key given to me by the repository owner? The owner has given me a repo link and an ssh key

Comment: @NKRVVI, I have shared more details in my above answer, see **EDIT_1**.